# what is difference between connection timeout and session timeout in curator

Tags: session, connection, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

when we create a curator client, we have

```
    RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryNTimes(3, 1000);
    CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkConnectString, 
            15000, // sessionTimeoutMs
            15000, // connectionTimeoutMs
            retryPolicy);
```

Can someone tell what is difference between session timeout and connection timeout in the above api call?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make API calls to ZooKeeper until the connection has been established (i.e. until you get `SyncConnected`). Curator internally waits until this connection has been established for you. `connectionTimeoutMs` is the max time to wait for this.

Comment: thanks for explanation. is there any relationship between connection timeout and session timeout, such as whether the session timeout should be the same as connection timeout or 2 or 3 times of it.

Comment: No - no relationship. The connection timeout is an invention of Curator and ZooKeeper (client and server) know nothing about it.

Comment: Session timeout has to be greater than connection timeout. Curator warns if that's not the case.